# Return the variable value as string in python

Tags: python, file, variables

Suppose I have two variables:

```
_first = True
_second = _first

print (getValue(_second))

>>> _first
```

Is there a way to implement getValue(or anything else) in that way ? I don't care about the real value (boole\int\string etc..) , just the name of the assigned variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables don't refer to each other.  When you use `_second = _first`, you aren't making _second refer to _first, you're making it refer to the value that _first refers to.  This might clear some things up: [Facts and Myths about Names and Values in Python](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Nice link, Ned! And it's nice to see you having fun with good old Graphviz. :) (FWIW, I programmed in various "traditional" languages (including C) for many years before coming to Python, but I'd learned about the binding approach to variables via PostScript, so I adapted to Python fairly quickly).

Answer (score 0):

No; once you've assigned `_first` to `_second`, there is no longer any connection between `_second` and where it got its value from (as opposed to the value itself).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot print out the variable's name in such a way.

But you might try using **Dictionary** so that you can have a **key-value** pair for each entry.

That way you can find the **values** corresponding to certain names as keys and get the **key names** as well.
I hope that helps you.

to get help on dictionaries you can refer:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm